# Why am I getting postcss warnings when I'm not using it?

Tags: postcss, nrwl-nx

I'm using NX to build a React demo and it has a dependency of `postcss` however I'm not using it and none of my webpack configs or anything else is using it either... Yet when I run `yarn start` I get the following warning in my CLI.

```
You did not set any plugins, parser, or stringifier. Right now, PostCSS does nothing. Pick plugins for your case on https://www.postcss.parts/ and use them in postcss.config.js.
```

Comment: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/5420 ?

Comment: cool, that would be great if they fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue has been resolved as @hallvors pointed out in this PR https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/5420